# WebRTC Relay Server / Broadcast multiple clients

Tags: webrtc

I've got WebRTC peer to peer working but when I want to broadcast a single camera to multiple clients obviously peer to peer isn't suitable.

I've found solutions like

- http://lynckia.com
  and
- http://www.medooze.com/products/mcu/webrtc-support.aspx

But the first I can't get setup (and it seems to have cross browser issues) 
the second just feels like we're hitting a nail with a nuclear missile.

All I need is a relay, I don't need to decode / recode streams.

I just need

- The Broadcaster to connect to the server (peer to peer)
- The clients to connect to the server (peer to peer)
- The server to relay the stream from the broadcaster to the clients.

Is there any software out there that offers this solution that I've missed? is there an alternative working and scalable alternative?

Thanks

Comment: have you checked out kurento media server?

Answer (score 3):

[Jitsi Video Bridge](https://jitsi.org/Projects/JitsiVideobridge) works pretty much exactly how you describe.

Comment: The only problem with Jitsi is it's extremely difficult to understand how to take an existing webrtc app and implement with jitsi video bridge.

Answer (score 1):

On your server you can run [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/), to which your broadcaster can provide a stream via RTP.

Have a look at an example [configuration file](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/blob/master/conf/janus.plugin.streaming.cfg.sample.in).

After writing a configuration file which defines how the server receives stream from the broadcaster, you should be able to launch janus in the background via a [command line interface tool](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway#configure-and-start):

`$ janus --daemon --config=config_file.conf`

Also, see [streaming test demo](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/streamingtest.html).

Note: I have not tested this thoroughly.

Comment: I was hoping that someone could break this down a little bit.  I feel like Janus takes WebRTC input, and reprocesses it for broadcasting, so that if thousands of people wanted to watch your broadcast, the server would happen dispensing the information, rather than your personal browser?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this github-repo](https://github.com/akshat7101999/WebRTC-scalable-broadcast-p2p) inspired from muaz khan's WebRTC p2p scalable broadcast. This can work great on LAN. On internet, I am not sure how well it can work as of now though we are improving it on the go.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to broadcast from a peer to a set of peers, if they don't care about the latency, the best solution is to covert WebRTC to live streaming, without transcoding just muxing:

```
Peer(Publisher) ---WebRTC--> Server --RTMP/HLS/DASH--> Peers/Players
```

> If this works good for you, [SRS](https://github.com/ossrs/srs) is able to covert WebRTC to live streaming.

Because live streaming allows you to use CDN or TCP to deliver the streams, and the latency is about 3~5s, so this solution is only available when `Peers/Players` never need to communicate to the `Peer(Publisher)`.

If you want all those peers to talk to each other, it's very complex and need a WebRTC SFU cluster to do this, there will be a huge number of streams. For example, if allows 100 peers to talk to each other, there will be 100x100 = 10k streams.

It's too complicated, so I don't think there is good open-source solution right now(at 2022.02).